# java API give the similarity of words

Tags: java, similarity, wordnet

i have two list of words, i want a `java API` to give me the similarity between these words. 
for example calculating Inverse document frequency, or Vector space model.

Comment: have you googled "Java Inverse document frequency" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the open source [S-Space](https://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/) package.